# ui-select - Como colocar atributo "name"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Probleminha aqui para variar, alguém já trabalhou com ui-select, estou usando em um projeto aqui dentro de um formulário de cadastro de cliente para selecionar estados e cidades, esta funcionando beleza, porém ele não aceita o atributo "name" e nem "requered" para que eu possa pegar depois quando submeter o formulário.

Esse é o exemplo de uso desse módulo:
http://plnkr.co/edit/a3KlK8dKH3wwiiksDSn2?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Sobre o valor você pode pegá-lo pelo ng-model ao submeter. Agora quanto ao required caso ele realmente não entenda eu indicaria a você criar uma diretiva que faça a validação

Comment: Eu criei um input hidden que recebia o valor desse select pelo ng-model, funcionou, mais ficou uma gambiarra feia. No fim das contas usei o select 2 via jquery mesmo, pois já estava sem paciência e tempo. Preciso estudar como se faz para criar diretivas que ainda não sei pois ainda não precisei. Valeu pela reposta @CaiqueGTR .